# How to map array of objects in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm trying to map array of objects and return widget with some value of given objects... Like this

```
 _metapodaci?.map<Widget>((e) => Text("Naziv dokumenta je ${e.label}")),
```

I get an error saying "The element type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget"
but when I map inside text widget like this:

```
 Text("Meta podaci: ${_metapodaci.map((e) => e.label)}"),
```

then _metapodaci are mapped good.
Here is Whole widget where I'm trying to map if needed:

```
 Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            
            child:   Expanded(
              child: _metapodaci.isEmpty ? 
              Text("Odaberite vrstu dokumenta") :
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Meta podaci: ${_metapodaci.map((e) => e.label)}"),
                  //_metapodaci.map<Widget>((e) => Text("Naziv dokumenta je ${e.label}")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your array to list of widget and also for null safety issue you need check for null before too , try this:

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: _metapodaci == null || _metapodaci!.isEmpty
                        ? Text("Odaberite vrstu dokumenta")
                        : Column(
                            children: _metapodaci!
                                .map<Widget>((e) =>
                                    Text("Naziv dokumenta je ${e.label}"))
                                .toList(),
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `toList()` method

```dart
 _metapodaci?.map<Widget>((e) => Text("Naziv dokumenta je ${e.label}")).toList(),
```

Comment: When I try it I get error: "The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'"